# How do i properly build my android app after nativescript version change

Tags: android, build.gradle, nativescript

I have an error with building my nativescript android app

I am using NativeScript 5.2 to develop an Android App. However one of my colleagues used NativeScript 6 to git push to the development branch. I pulled it and tns migrate and it can no longer be built. It keeps showing Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.

I have tried upgrading my NativeScript to his version, and I've also tried reverting the NativeScript and git branch, but it still shows the same error.

error code:

```
 Gradle build...
         + setting applicationId
         + applying user-defined configuration from C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\app\App_Resources\Android\app.gradle
         + using support library version 28.0.0
         + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\node_modules\nativescript-background-http\platforms\android\nativescript_background_http.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\node_modules\nativescript-camera\platforms\android\nativescript_camera.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\node_modules\nativescript-fingerprint-auth\platforms\android\nativescript_fingerprint_auth.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\node_modules\nativescript-loading-indicator\platforms\android\nativescript_loading_indicator.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\node_modules\nativescript-material-textfield\platforms\android\nativescript_material_textfield.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\node_modules\nativescript-pager\platforms\android\nativescript_pager.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\node_modules\nativescript-plugin-firebase\platforms\android\firebase-release.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\node_modules\nativescript-plugin-firebase\platforms\android\nativescript_plugin_firebase.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\node_modules\nativescript-material-core\platforms\android\nativescript_material_core.aar
         + adding aar plugin dependency: C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\node_modules\tns-core-modules-widgets\platforms\android\widgets-release.aar

    registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection) registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

C:\Users\Le\Documents\Work\work-app-investor\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:2-47:16 to override.
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:2-47:16 to override.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 2s
Unable to apply changes on device: 8DQCIF45VCSOTOYH. Error is: Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Please do not attach an image. Always provide text format code/output/error message etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by checking your plugins for AndroidX support - you seem to have a few, based on your build messages.
Usually you will just need to update them in your `package.json`, do a `tns platform clean android` and build again.

Comment: This is my answer. apparently my nativescript-material-core was updated to version 2.3.* above, in which in that they migrated to AndroidX.